# How to pass a Date value to java API call in Different format?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a date column in my table, which will display a date as '17-MAR-15' format. Now I need to pass the date as 'DD-MM-YYYY(17-03-2015)' format to the Java API call. How can I pass this date parameter in that format?

Comment: what's the reason you can't use a search engine?

Comment: The DATE type column in MySQL does not have any format whatsoever. In selects it's formatted using ISO format 2015-03-17. If you have dates stored like "17-MAT-15" it means you have a VARCHAR type column to store your dates, in which case any date formatting functions won't work.

Comment: martynasma's not quite correct. However, while the date/time functions can help, it's far better to fix your column to use a date data type.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at: [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)
But basically what you do is this:
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dateColumn, '%d-%m-%Y') FROM xyz;

Edit: Well, should have waited until I was really awake to answer, but if you happen to convert your date column to the date type this is how you would get the date in the specified format.